# Odata How to Authorization on $expand functionality of user Roles?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, authorization, odata

I want to restrict access to $expand operation Based on Roles. My problem need to restrict access to some entity for user Roles.can someone gives some hints on where to start?

Comment: I was looking for away to do this months ago. I ended up using multi-tenancy on my Database, which automically will filter my deb to what a user can access

Comment: @johnny5 see my Answer

Comment: nice I’ll check the implementation later

Comment: @johnny5 thanks for upVote :)

Comment: Anytime, I always remember too for someone who helps me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do AUTHORIZATION using this code snippetI get that from http://www.software-architects.com/devblog/2014/09/12/10-OData-FAQs
easy with too much code

```
[Authorize]
[ODataRoutePrefix("Customer")]
public class CustomerController : ODataController
{
    [...]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(((ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal).Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "IsAdmin").Value))
        {
            return Ok(context.Customers);
        }
        return Unauthorized();
    }

    [...]
}
```

or Create Extensions Method IEdmModelBuilder more reference in

> [ODataAuthorizationQueryValidatorSample](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/ODataAuthorizationQueryValidatorSample) on git hub

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.OData;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;

namespace MHS.Assessments.WebAPI.Utilities
{
    public static class IEdmModelBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static void AddAuthorizedRolesAnnotations(this IEdmModel edmModel)
        {
            var typeAnnotationsMapping = edmModel.SchemaElementsAcrossModels()
                .OfType<IEdmEntityType>()
                .Where(t => edmModel.GetAnnotationValue<ClrTypeAnnotation>(t) != null)
                .Select(t => edmModel.GetAnnotationValue<ClrTypeAnnotation>(t).ClrType)
                .ToDictionary(clrType => clrType,
                              clrType => clrType.GetCustomAttributes<CanExpandAttribute>(inherit: false));

            foreach (var kvp in typeAnnotationsMapping)
            {
                foreach (var attribute in kvp.Value)
                {
                    attribute.SetRoles(edmModel, kvp.Key);
                }
            }
        }


        public static void SetAuthorizedRolesOnType(this IEdmModel model,string typeName,string[] roles)
        {
            IEdmEntityType type = model.FindType(typeName) as IEdmEntityType;
            if (type == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The authorized element must be an entity type");
            }

            model.SetAnnotationValue<AuthorizedRoles>(type, new AuthorizedRoles(roles));
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.ca

```
edmModel.SetAuthorizedRolesOnType("Customers", new string[] { "Support"});
```